# Angularjs- how to check child form validity in parent form

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have used ui.router with nested ui-views and I want to check the inner form validity to enable common button used for multiple nested views.

Please help me out

Comment: question is unclear, though a better approach is to have directives with `ng-form`. That way form validity can be handled easily no matter how nested it is.

Comment: Actually i have multiple tabs, forming to nested states of parent state, and have common button to save all tabs data, for that i want to enable the button, if all forms are validated true.

Comment: In this case, better to have a `$rootScope` varibale but `$rootScope` is not recommended. You can have a `service`, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

set a variable in the parent controller. use it directly from child controller. For example,

```
$scope.childFormValid = false; // this should be in parent controller.
```

Now, in child controller,

```
$scope.childFormValid = true; // this sets the value of parent scope variable.
```

Parent views variables are always accessible in child view. But not in states.

Comment: I have uib-tabs for nested views, when should i set $scope.childFormValid = true; value

Comment: How can you have child views in tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Considering for each tab's ui-view html, you have below html structure with `required` attribute set for the UI Elements:

```
<ng-form name='tab1-N'>...</ng-form>
```

And suppose your parent html which contains the common `save all` button, has below html structure

```
<ng-form name='parentForm'>..</ng-form>
```

You can then just add a `ng-disabled` attribute to your save all button, as all tab validations would indirectly set the validity of parent form:

```
<input type='button' ng-disabled='!parentForm.$valid'....
```